# Sending json msg with attachment to http:outbound-endpoint Mule 3.5

Tags: java, rest, jersey, mule, attachment

Edited to update question:

I would like to send an attachment AND some json via a mule http:outbound endpoint using Mule 3.5

Updated Question:

I am trying to use the mule transormers  and  in the same outbound endpoint request, can that be done?

`<set-attachment attachmentName="attach-Attachment1" contentType="text/plain" doc:name="Attach text file" value="#[bin1]"/>
<set-payload value="{'Attachment1' : 'file.txt'}"/> 
<http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" 
            host="${myhost}" port="${myPort}"  method="POST"   mimeType="multipart/form-data"  doc:name="HTTP" path="myPath" >`

Original question:
Can I do something like this?

1. In a Java Transformer, build the http Entity :

   ```
       // build the JSON entry
   String json = "{ \"values\" : { ";
   json += "\"Submitter\" : \"Allen\", ";
   json += "\"Short Description\" : \"testing 123\", ";
   json += "\"Attachment1\" : <Base64 encoded file data String here> ;
   json += " } }";

   // build the multipart entity
   HttpEntity entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
           .addTextBody("entry", json, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON)
           .addBinaryBody("attach-Attachment1", new File(filename))
           .build();
   ```
2. Return this HttpEntity object from the Java transformer to the mule flow in the message payload.
3. Pass the resulting mule message in the flow to an http:outbound-endpoint

I am trying to build a mule flow which will send an attachment to a rest service that expects the request to contain Multipart form data.  I would like to pass the entity to the outbound endpoint, so that the request is made via the mule flow, and not inside the java transformer.

I do have code I can post here as a possible solution for others finding this post, I had to look back at old code because my employer decided to change our stack and we are no longer using Mule. So, putting this as a disclaimer, I can't remember if this bit of code in my mule flow was ever tested.     `

```
            <set-variable variableName="attaches" value="#[new java.util.HashMap()]" doc:name="Variable"/>
            <!-- note, message object inside for loop is not same message as in flow, after for loop, original message is not changed, so 
                 we can't add attachments to actual mule flow message   inside for loop, we need to put the attachments into a hashmap, then 
                 outside the loop add the attachments to the mule Message object  -->
            <foreach collection="#[message.payload.binaryEncodedAttachmentData.entrySet()]">
                <!-- Payload is now a Map.Entry object --> 
                <logger message="key is #[payload.key]" level="INFO" doc:name="LoggerPayloadError" />
                <logger message="value is #[payload.value]" level="INFO" doc:name="LoggerPayloadError" />
                <set-attachment attachmentName="#[payload.key]" contentType="text/plain" doc:name="Attach text file" value="#[payload.value]"/>
                <expression-component doc:name="Expression">
                    <![CDATA[java.util.Set keys = message.outboundAttachments.keySet();
                                                for(Object key:keys){
                                                 flowVars.attaches.put(key, message.outboundAttachments.get(key));
                                                }]]>
                </expression-component>
           </foreach> 
           <expression-component doc:name="Expression">
               <![CDATA[message.outboundAttachments.putAll(flowVars.attaches);]]>
           </expression-component>

           <logger message="done adding attachments" level="INFO" doc:name="Done Adding Attach" />

          <!-- done adding attachments --> 
      </when>`
```

** note documentation indicates that the payload should be null after adding attachments, so this code followed the above code which added the attachments, the debugging bit may be helpful to other developers finding this question, also please note disclaimer above that this code is untested!

```
            `<set-payload value="#[null]" /> 
            <!--  below code for debugging only -->
                 <set-variable variableName="dh1" value="#[message.outboundAttachments['attach-Attachment1']]"></set-variable> 
                 <set-variable variableName="dh2" value="#[message.outboundAttachments['entry']]"></set-variable><expression-component>
                 <![CDATA[
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(4);
                DataHandler dh1 = flowVars.dh1;
        dh1.writeTo(baos);
        System.out.println("<<attach-Attachment1>>");
        System.out.println(baos.toString());
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos2 = new ByteArrayOutputStream(4);          
                DataHandler dh2 = flowVars.dh2;
        dh2.writeTo(baos2);
        System.out.println("<<entry>>");
        System.out.println(baos2.toString());        
                ]]></expression-component>

            <!--  end code for debugging only -->`
```

Comment: Have you tried just adding the attachment with a `<set-attachment>` component before the outbound endpoint? Setting the entity to the body won't work because the HTTP outbound endpoint has it's own logic to transform payload and attachments to a multipart request.

Comment: Ah thank you very much @afelisatti.  I will give that a try.

Comment: Hi.. Did you achive the same .. if Yes. pls share the flow and details.. I am facing same situation now.

Comment: Hi @Pedantic,  I do have code I can post here, I had to look back at old code because my employer decided to change our stack and we are no longer using Mule.  So, putting this as a disclaimer, I can't remember if this bit of code in my mule flow was ever tested.

Comment: Thanks @Kimk,  I used the same approach and its working like a charm.. thanks for your prompt reply.